# Reference request: irregular adjectives

Tags: adjective, reference

Where can I find a decent list of irregular adjectives, i.e. *gut - besser - am besten*?

Comment: In addition to Em1's answer, I suggest googling for "unregelmäßige Adjektive".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- gut,   besser,   am besten
- viel,   mehr,   am meisten
- gern,   lieber,   am liebsten
- hoch,   höher,   am höchsten
- dunkel,   dunkler,   am dunkelsten
- teuer,   teurer,   am teuersten
- groß,   größer,   am größten
- arg, ärger, am ärgsten
- bange, banger / bänger, am bangsten / bängsten
- blass, blasser / blässer, am blassesten / blässesten
- dumm, dümmer, am dümmsten
- fromm, frommer / frömmer, am frommsten / frömmsten
- gesund, gesünder / gesunder, am gesündesten / gesundesten
- glatt, glätter / glatter, am glättesten / glattesten
- grob, gröber, am gröbsten
- hoch (aber: der hohe Turm), höher, am höchsten
- karg, karger / kärger, am kargsten / kärgsten
- klug, klüger, am klügsten
- krank, kränker, am kränksten
- nah / nahe, näher, am nächsten (nicht: nähesten)
- nass, nasser / nässer, am nassesten / nässesten
- schmal, schmäler / schmaler, am schmälsten / schmalsten
- schwarz, schwärzer, am schwärzesten
- teuer (aber: das teure Essen), teurer, am teuersten
- wenig, weniger / minder, am wenigsten / mindesten
- rot, roter / röter, am rotesten / am rötesten

http://www.deutschakademie.de/online-deutschkurs/forum/index.php?topic=79.0

http://www.cafe-lingua.de/deutsche-grammatik/unregelmaessige-steigerung.php

Answer (score 5):

Here is [a list with the most used irregular adjectives](http://www.cafe-lingua.de/deutsche-grammatik/unregelmaessige-steigerung.php).

One frequently used adjective is missing in that list:

- gerne – lieber – (am) liebste(n)

Because I did not find any better reference, here are some additional notes:

Superlative only:

- innere - innerste
- äußere - äußerste
- vorder - vorderste
- hintere - hinterste
- untere - unterste

Absolute, invariable and some compound adjectives:

- tot, lebendig
- einmalig, einzig, einzigartig
- sondergleichen, unvergleichbar
- ganz, kein, absolut, maximal, minimal, total, voll, extrem
- schwanger, kinderlos
- dreieckig
- schriftlich
- stumm
- golden
- steinhart
- himmelweit, riesengroß

Note: This list is still incomplete.

Comment: _Gerne_ is missing in that list because it's an adverb, not an adjective. You'll find it on the [page about adverbs](http://www.cafe-lingua.de/deutsche-grammatik/adverbien-umstandswoerter.php). (Still it's not bad to mention _gerne_ in your answer.) More adverbs in your list: _sondergleichen_ and _kein_.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Oups. Das stimmt. Danke für den Hinweis ;p